Solving $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\left(x^2+4\right)^2} e^{-3|t-x|} d x$ using Fourier transform, how to approach this?
The question is to solve the following integral: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\left(x^2+4\right)^2} e^{-3|t-x|} d x$
I tried to think of it like convolution, but this needs one more integral like this $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ so this doesn't look like a good one.
I tried to think of the main formula of the Fourier transform, which is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-i \omega t} d t$ and letting $\omega$ be $0$, so it would end up like $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) d t$, but I still have two functions, and the first looks like differentiated.
I mean how could I get the Fourier transform for $e^{-3|t-x|}$ and $\frac{x}{\left(x^2+4\right)^2}$ together without having the conditions for convolution.
If it's, potentially, convolution it should have looked like this: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\left(x^2+4\right)^2} e^{-3|t-x|} d x$, shouldn't it?
Any one who have hints, or who could nudge me in the right direction to solving this problem, or just referring some text book which has similar examples, that will be a great help for me.

Edit
I tried taking the Fourier transform of the whole thing, but still stuck, here is what I got:
$$\mathcal{F}\left\{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\left(x^2+4\right)^2} e^{-3|t-x|} dx\right\} = \mathcal{F}\left\{ \frac{x}{\left(x^2+4\right)^2} \right\} \mathcal{F}\left\{ e^{-3|x|} \right\}$$
Which leads to:
$$ \left(\frac{6}{9 + \omega^2}\right) \frac{-1}{2}\mathcal{F}\left\{\frac{-2x}{(\omega^2+4)^2}\right\} $$
$$ = \left(\frac{6}{9 + \omega^2}\right) \frac{-1}{2i}\mathcal{F}\left\{\frac{d}{d\omega}\frac{1}{\omega^2+4}\right\} $$
$$ = \left(\frac{6}{9 + \omega^2}\right) \frac{i}{8}\mathcal{F}\left\{\frac{d}{d\omega}\frac{4}{\omega^2+4}\right\} $$
$$ = \frac{i}{8} \left(\frac{6}{9 + \omega^2}\right) \left( -2\pi \omega e^{-2|\omega|}\right)$$
, isn't it? just I need to get the inverse of the Fourier transform now, so trying as follows:
$$ \frac{-3i\pi}{4} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{9 + \omega^2}\ \omega e^{-2|\omega|}\ e^{i\omega t} d\omega $$
$$ \frac{-3i\pi}{4} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{9 + \omega^2}\ \omega e^{-2|\omega|+ i\omega t}\ d\omega $$
$$ \frac{-3i}{8} \left[\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{1}{9 + \omega^2}\ \omega e^{(2+ it)\omega}\ d\omega + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{9 + \omega^2}\ \omega e^{(-2+ it)\omega}\ d\omega \right] $$
After this, how should I proceed? since I don't feel like this integral is doable with my knowledge of integration by parts or even using some recursive formula.

I think you have forgotten the definition of convolution. What is given is the convolution of $e^{-3|x|}$ and $\frac{x}{\left(x^2+4\right)^2}$.

No, I know that the convolution is: $\mathcal{F}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) g(t-x) dt} = F(\omega) G(\omega)$, isn't it? my problem is, that the main integral of the Fourier transform itself is missing, so how could I solve it using the convolution property if it's not even a fourier transform?

Take the inverse transform of $F(\omega)G(\omega)$.

I'll edit the question so I can add clearly what I have got, but still stuck

The convolution theorem assumes the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ is defined as $$F(\omega)=\mathcal{F}xf(x)=\int\limits{-\infty}^\infty f(x), e^{-2 \pi i \omega x}, dx$$ and the inverse Fourier transform of $F(\omega)$ is defined as $$f(x)=\mathcal{F}{\omega}^{-1}F(\omega)=\int\limits{-\infty}^\infty F(\omega), e^{2 \pi i x \omega}, d\omega$$ so you're formulas are incorrect.

Oh, that's pretty embarrassing, because it's written like this in the professor's lecture notes

I have looked for some articles, and I got that my statements were fine, may I don't get your point. May you please clarify more for me.

This is not a complete answer, but is intended to clarify the correct approach.

For
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{\left(x^2+4\right)^2}\tag{1}$$
with Fourier transform
$$F(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x[f(x)](\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\, e^{-i 2 \pi \omega x} \, dx=-\frac{1}{2} i \pi^2 e^{-4 \pi \omega} \omega \left(e^{8 \pi \omega} \theta(-\omega)+\theta(\omega)\right)\tag{2}$$
and
$$g(x)=e^{-3 |x|}\tag{3}$$
with Fourier transform
$$G(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x[g(x)](\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)\, e^{-i 2 \pi \omega x} \, dx=\frac{6}{4 \pi^2 \omega^2+9}\tag{4}$$
the convolution
$$h(t)=[f(x) * g(x)](t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\, g(t-x) \, dx\tag{5}$$
can be evaluated as the inverse Fourier transform
$$h(t)=\mathcal{F}_{\omega}^{-1}[F(\omega) G(\omega)](t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega)\, G(\omega) e^{i 2 \pi t \omega} \, d\omega\tag{6}.$$

Mathematica gives the convolution result as either a sum involving four exponential integral $E_i(z)$ functions or as a sum involving four exponential integral $E_1(z)$ functions, so perhaps the convolution result follows from the definitions of these functions which can be found at Wolfram MathWorld: Exponential Integral.

Sorry for missing it, but what is $\theta$ appearing in the expression of $F(\omega)$?

@JianingSong In formula (2) above, $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function, so you can evaluate the inverse Fourier transform integral in formula (6) above as $$h(t)=-3 i \pi^2 \left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^0 \frac{\omega, e^{4 \pi \omega}}{4 \pi^2 \omega^2+9}, e^{i 2 \pi t \omega} , d\omega+\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\omega, e^{-4 \pi \omega}}{4 \pi^2 \omega^2+9}, e^{i 2 \pi t \omega} , d\omega\right).$$
